# Linear operator relative to basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

For each $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ let $E_{ij} \in \mathrm{End}(\mathbf{V})$
be the linear operator defined by

\begin{equation*} E_{ij} \mathbf{e}_k = \langle \mathbf{e}_j,\mathbf{e}_k \rangle \mathbf{e}_i, \quad 1 \leq k \leq n.
  \end{equation*}

What is the matrix of $E_{ij}$ relative to $\mathcal{B}$ (the standard basis)?

I believe $E_{ij}$ is a matrix of zeroes with 1 in the $i,j$ position. How would you obtain the matrix relative to $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: You don't say what $B$ is. Presumably it's a basis, and just the set of vectors $e_i$. Now just check your answer for the standard basis in, say, $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes B is the standard basis. What do you mean by "check your answer"?

Comment: If you work at understanding the definition of "a matrix of a transformation  relative to a basis" you will see why your answer is correct.

Comment: Please edit the body of your question with the information about the meaning of $B$. Users shouldn't have to sift through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker got it thanks!

Comment: @GerryMyerson done

Comment: @kabir.987 You can answer your own question now, and accept the answer. so the question does not remain on  the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(k,l)$-matrix element of $[E_{ij}]_\mathcal{B}$ is

\begin{equation*}
   \langle \mathbf{e}_k, E_{ij} \mathbf{e}_l \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_k, \langle \mathbf{e}_j,\mathbf{e}_l \rangle\mathbf{e}_i \rangle
   = \langle \mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e}_k\rangle \langle \mathbf{e}_j,\mathbf{e}_l\rangle.
  \end{equation*}

Thus, the matrix $[E_{ij}]_\mathcal{B}$ has a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-position and all other matrix elements are $0$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).